# Htaccess redirect static sub-domain to domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I created some static sub-domains for images:

```
www.static1.domain.com
www.static2.domain.com
```

Now I want to redirect files that are not images from static domains to www.domain.com, to avoid duplicate content. I have these rules in my htaccess (non-existing files are redirected to index.php silently):

```
#Redirect static to main
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} static([0-9]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

#Redirect non exisitng files to index.php (silent)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

The redirect works fine. But if I enter a non-existing image e.g. http://www.static1.domain.com/test.gif, I am redirectd to http://www.domain.com/index.php.

**The redirect of test.gif should be a silent redirect to index php** ... what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for hints.

Comment: Do you have some 404 handler somewhere in httpd.cond or .htaccess? I suggest you to post your matching access.log and error.log when you send above request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it this way. Throws the default server 404 Page when http://www.static1.domain.com/test.gif is not found. Not best, but well.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !static([0-9]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} static([0-9]+)\.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly. By silent redirect to you mean that "index.php" shouldn't be in the url bar or do you mean the url bar should still read "test.gif" but the page should render index.php?

Comment: Second one: the bar should read test.gif but render index.php

Comment: Change
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
to
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]

This may work, it's what I have on a couple of my redirects and it works as you want.

Comment: Does not make a difference. The silent redirect works fine, but not in combination with the redirect from static to main.

Comment: Ah, it won't be "silent" because you're changing domain.

Comment: Should't the line RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f prevent the redirect from static.domain to domain if the file does not exist?

Comment: Your redirect when the file doesn't exist probably triggers your original redirect rule which says if it isn't an image then redirect to non-static?

I'm not sure, sorry. That's my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add multiple `RewriteCond` lines. Only the last one applies to `RewriteRule`.

So this line does not have any effect:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
```

And that is why non existing images are also being redirected.

How about:

```
#Redirect non exisitng files to index.php (silent)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

#Redirect static to main
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This seems to lead to an infinite loop.

Comment: Then try to re-add the RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} static([0-9]+)\. line.